# jQuery Selector Expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have problem with my jQuery code where my Firebug gives me warning: Selector expected.

Here is the code:

```
$("img[id$='_tick']").each(function() {

    $(this).click(function() {

        var tickIDFinder = $(this).attr("id");
        var tickSection = tickIDFinder.slice(0,1);

        var checkboxID = "\"input[id^='" + tickSection + "_checkbox_']\"";
        var airTableID = "#" + tickSection + "_airline_table tr";

        $(checkboxID).each(function() {

            if ( $(this).is('checked') ) {
                alert("Checkbox is Checked.");
            }

            $(this).attr('checked','checked');

        });

    });

});
```

What I'm trying to do is write a jQuery to allow users click a link (as an image). When the users click on this image, it will then 'checked' all the checkbox specified. It will then I got the Selector expected warning from my Firebug.

The jQuery itself is working as I expected. I just want to try to fix warning.

Anyone can help? I would really appreciate it.

Thank heaps for your thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, this can be simplified even further, like this:

```
$("img[id$='_tick']").click(function() {
  var tickSection = this.id.slice(0,1);

  var checkboxID = "input[id^='" + tickSection + "_checkbox_']";
  var airTableID = "#" + tickSection + "_airline_table tr";

  $(checkboxID).each(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
          alert("Checkbox is Checked.");
      }
      $(this).attr('checked', true);
  });
});
```

A few things here:

- you don't need a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), just [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and it'll bind to all of them.
- use DOM properties when available, e.g. `this.id` and `this.checked`
- the selector for `checkboxID` had extra quotes, remove them

Likely without the debugging, it's even simpler, as [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) works on multiple elements as well:

```
$("img[id$='_tick']").click(function() {
  $("input[id^='" + this.id.slice(0,1) + "_checkbox_']").attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: I got couple reference that doing .each() and .click() might not doing me any good. Thank you for confirming that for me.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
var checkboxID = "\"input[id^='" + tickSection + "_checkbox_']\"";
```

with

```
var checkboxID = "input[id^='" + tickSection + "_checkbox_']";
```

(in addition to what @rahul said :)

Comment: Thank you for this. Once I change this, and the :checked, I don't get the warning anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if ( $(this).is('checked'))
```

with

```
if ( $(this).is(':checked'))
```

See [**`:checked`**](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

You can use `this.id` which will be faster than `$(this).attr("id")`

```
var tickIDFinder = this.id;
```

Comment: While this is correct in what he's after...it wouldn't cause the error he's getting, and `$(this).is(':checked')` should be `this.checked` anyway.